# Multiple dotnet core versions on Linux Docker image

Tags: docker, .net-core

How can I run and install multiple versions of the dotnet core framework (say 2.1 and 1.1) in a docker container on Linux?

Below is my current dockerfile and I want to add dotnet 1.1 to it as well.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.403-sdk-bionic

ENV DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE true
ENV DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT true

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y zip
```

Answer (score 17):

You can simply copy the runtime from each image.

For example, use this Dockerfile to have **.NET 5.0 + .NET Core 3.1 + .NET Core 2.1 + ASP.NET** runtime:

```
# Start with .NET Core 2.1 runtime.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1

# Add .NET Core 3.1 runtime.
COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet

# Add .NET 5.0 runtime.
COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet
```

Build and run:

```sh
$ docker build -t my-image . && docker run --entrypoint dotnet my-image --list-runtimes
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile

... omitted for brevity ...

#4 [stage-0 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1
#4 sha256:7d63f34a82584570b0e746ac940d81e903407f58f85148263fc25428d5437fa8
#4 DONE 0.0s

#6 [stage-0 2/3] COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet
#6 sha256:cddc840a53b9711f017ed9e285efd2d27cfc0216fc1c2fb5f2383a2f52fbf735
#6 CACHED

#8 [stage-0 3/3] COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet
#8 sha256:d34576b2af16f150960c3b5a974d34bf97568dbc42899e359bb1bac6dc584307
#8 CACHED

#9 exporting to image
#9 sha256:e8c613e07b0b7ff33893b694f7759a10d42e180f2b4dc349fb57dc6b71dcab00
#9 exporting layers done
#9 writing image sha256:61c1518c7fb1bffff0ca77410e2a5be5febae9669fb6dc695edb053190ad98c3 done
#9 naming to docker.io/library/my-image done
#9 DONE 0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.18 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.18 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: This will overwrite the CLI tool /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet with the older version, which probably isn't what you want. You can do `RUN mkdir /dotnet-backup && find /usr/share/dotnet -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp -l {} /dotnet-backup/ \;` before the copies and `RUN mv /dotnet-backup/* /usr/share/dotnet/ && rmdir /dotnet-backup` after to keep the .NET 5.0 versions.

Comment: @MarkRaymond You're right. I agree. I've reversed the order of the steps so that the newest runtime would now overwrite the older ones.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of multiple dotnet core framework.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-runtime-deps-stretch-slim

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        curl \
        wget \
        gpg \
        apt-transport-https \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update

# Install .NET Core Runtime v1.1.2
ENV DOTNET_VERSION 1.1.2
ENV DOTNET_DOWNLOAD_URL https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release/1.1.0/Binaries/$DOTNET_VERSION/dotnet-debian-x64.$DOTNET_VERSION.tar.gz

RUN curl -SL $DOTNET_DOWNLOAD_URL --output dotnet.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
    && tar -zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet \
    && rm dotnet.tar.gz \
    && ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet

# Install ASP.NET Core
ENV ASPNETCORE_VERSION 2.2.1
RUN curl -SL --output aspnetcore.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/aspnetcore/Runtime/$ASPNETCORE_VERSION/aspnetcore-runtime-$ASPNETCORE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && aspnetcore_sha512='e027a5dada5d139a44675f28090f996375e49fbd72f7897aa925e48803632d5bf187d4f22dc8225505ac33e6a7a05dcdd8ed19d8b6d5e46b22e628315cf13e3e' \
    && echo "$aspnetcore_sha512  aspnetcore.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
    && tar -zxf aspnetcore.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet \
    && rm aspnetcore.tar.gz \
    && ln -sf /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
```

And here is the result from within the instance

```
root@cb87fda4dfc7:/# dotnet --info

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.1
  Commit:  878dd11e62

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: I get an error after i try run a dotnet build
true
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

Comment: well you need to update to script for your needs. Don't hesitate to add the correct script to install what you need from the documentation